# Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have several DropdownList, however there are two on which I am using SelectedIndexChange event.
I am trying to get data from Database and fill respective DropdownList with values.
Earlier I had an issue where both Dropdownlist gets same value, whichever code is written later.
Then somehow that was fixed then I am getting this error .

> Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Heres how I am getting data from database :

```
string sqlqry = "select * from Newenrollee where enrollecode=@enrollecode ";
//SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, conn);
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollecode", txtenrolleecode.Text);
    dt.Rows.Clear();
    da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da1.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string regdate = (Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["dateofappointment"])).ToString();
        DDLAPDay.Text = regdate.Substring(0, 2);
        int mnthAD = (Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["dateofappointment"])).Month;
        string mnthAD1 = "";
        if (mnthAD > 0 && mnthAD < 10)
            mnthAD1 = "0" + mnthAD.ToString();
        else
            mnthAD1 = mnthAD.ToString();

        DDLADMonth.Text = mnthAD1;
        DDLADYear.ClearSelection();

        DDLADYear.Text = (Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["dateofappointment"])).Year.ToString();
        DDLDay.Text = DOB.Text.Substring(0, 2);
        int daydob = (Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DOB"])).Month;
        string daydob1 = "";
        if (daydob > 0 && daydob < 10)
            daydob1 = "0" + daydob.ToString();
        else
            daydob1 = daydob.ToString();
        DDLMonth.Text = daydob1.ToString();
        DDLYear.ClearSelection();
        DDLYear.Text = (Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DOB"])).Year.ToString();
    }
}
```

These are the Dropdownlist that I am using.
Let me know what is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: did you tried debugging your code and checked what's going wrong ?

Comment: If you want to select multiple items, then you should set `SelectionMode="Multiple"` for each `ListBox` since [dropdownlist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xy14hwwb%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) doesn't support multi-select.

Comment: @aspiring I want only single selection , so I used DropdownlIst

Comment: @nadeem I did when it goes to **DDLYear** it changes value of **DDLADYear** also, but somehow that got fixed but now I am getting this error

Comment: @mark try setting selection to none. e.g. `DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;` or put this line `DDLADYear.ClearSelection();` after all of your convert codes.

Comment: Where do you insert the items into the dropdownlist from the data table?

Comment: @aspiring I tried that, put `.ClearSelection();` above every DropdownList , but same error

Comment: @aspiring I do it on Page_Load using `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem lt = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();
                DDLYear.Items.Add("YYYY");`  and a for loop to get years

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80242/discussion-between-aspiring-and-mark).